# Dependencyproperty doesn't have value on load

Tags: c#, silverlight, dependency-properties

My problem is this, I have a UC called profile that contains another UC called FollowImageControl.

In my Profile.xaml i declaretively bind a property of FollowImageControl called FollowerId to a CurrentUserId from Profile.xaml.cs. Problem is that I CurrentUserId is assigned in Profile.xaml.cs; the Profile.xaml code-behind.

This means that I do not initially get the FollowerId. I have these methods in the **FollowImageControl.xaml.cs**:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty _followUserId =
                    DependencyProperty.Register("FollowUserId", typeof(Guid), typeof(FollowImageControl), null);
    public Guid FollowUserId
    {
        get { return (Guid)GetValue(_followUserId); }
        set { SetValue(_followUserId, value); }
    }
    public FollowImageControl()
    {
        // Required to initialize variables
        InitializeComponent();
        LoggedInUserId = WebContext.Current.User.UserId;
        var ctx = new NotesDomainContext();
        if (ctx.IsFollowingUser(LoggedInUserId, FollowUserId).Value) SwitchToDelete.Begin();
    }


    private void AddImg_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (LoggedInUserId != FollowUserId)
        {
            var ctx = new NotesDomainContext();
            ctx.FollowUser(FollowUserId, LoggedInUserId);
            ctx.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
```

**THE WEIRD THING IS** that when i insert breakpoints the FollowerUserId in FollowImageControl() is 0, but it has a value in AddImg_MouseLeftButtonDown, and there is no inbetween logic that sets the value of it. How is this???

Here's a little more code info:

This is my binding from **profile.xaml**

```
<internalCtrl:FollowImageControl FollowUserId="{Binding ElementName=ProfileCtrl, Path=CurrentUserId}" />
```

this is my constructor in **profile.xaml.cs**  wherein the CurrentUserId is set
public static readonly DependencyProperty _CurrentUserId =

```
DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentUserId", typeof(Guid), typeof(Profile), null);
        public Guid CurrentUserId 
        {
            get { return (Guid)GetValue(_CurrentUserId); }
            set { SetValue(_CurrentUserId, value); }
        }

public Profile(Guid UserId) {
            CurrentUserId = UserId;
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Profile_Loaded);
        }
```

I'm seriously dumbfound that one minute the FollowerId has no value, and the next it holds the right, without me having changed the value in the code-behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did you set the breakpoint in the `FollowImageControl` constructor? If you had set it before the call to `InitializeComponent()`, this is normal behavior because `InitializeComponent()` executes all the XAML. This means, also your binding is created in this method, so that there should be a value after `InitializeComponent()` has been called, but not before. Of course, `AddImg_MouseLeftButtonDown` is called after your constructor has completed, and thus `InitializeComponent()` has also been called.

Comment: I set the breakpoint after the initializecomponent(). It runs the full constructorcode without assigning a value to FollowerId. Thanks for your attention :)

Comment: I suspect that the FollowImageControl UC contained in Profile is loaded before the profile currentid value is set, and that it's causing the problem, but how then can I pass down the value?

Comment: it turned out the problem was totally unrelated to this, but in most cases I'm sure your answer would be the correct one, so I'm flagging your answer

Comment: DependencyPropertys are set by InitializeComponent() of the outer control. So just in its own ctor it is not yet set.